# Picker's items from database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, picker

I added a picker in my HomePage.xaml on my Xamarin cross platform app.

```
<Picker x:Name="myPicker"></Picker>
```

I want picker's items to come from a table column in the database(sqlite.) How can i do that.

```
myPicker.Items=???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a List from you database

something like

```
List<string> list = await GetStringFromDb();

myPicker.Items = list;
```

Current "pre" should have a bindable picker that has some nice stuff.

Otherwise [Here](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentialsSample#controls) a bindable picker